# Problem with adding placemark from kml file with specific id

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I have a problem with adding a vector layer from kml file. I am trying to make XMLHttpRequest and add only a placemark with specific id. Nothing is displaying on the map. Request is successful and variable data contains proper snippet of kml file. I'm pretty sure I'm making some noob mistake. Here is my code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

var idOfPlacemark = "test"; 
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();                         
req.open('GET', 'boundaries.kml', false);           
req.send(null);                                         
if(req.status == 200) dump(req.responseText);

var data = req.responseXML.querySelector("[id=" + idOfPlacemark + "]"); 
var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML;
test_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("test");
test_placemark = format.read(data.outerHTML);

test_layer.addFeatures(test_placemark);
map.addLayer(test_layer);

var layer_switcher= new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({});
map.addControl(layer_switcher);

var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(19.274483, 50.203275)
    .transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    );
var zoom=13;
map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
```

And here is my kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Document>
<Placemark id="test">
    <name>Name of placemark</name>
    <description>This is descr</description>
    <Polygon>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
            <coordinates> 19.212462, 50.200544
                        19.21287, 50.200399
                        19.21346, 50.19998
                        19.213857, 50.199603
                        19.214146, 50.199548
                        19.214715, 50.199541
                        19.215766, 50.199761
                        19.216743, 50.199987
                        19.217311, 50.200083
                        19.218041, 50.200028
                        19.21876, 50.199871
                        19.219178, 50.19961
                        19.219446, 50.199376
                        19.219253, 50.199046
                        19.218331, 50.198318
                        19.217741, 50.197845
                        19.217333, 50.197508
                        19.217086, 50.196986
                        19.216421, 50.196279
                        19.215606, 50.196004
                        19.214737, 50.196024
                        19.213996, 50.196182
                        19.213331, 50.196423
                        19.212065, 50.197055
                        19.211089, 50.1977
                        19.210874, 50.198298
                        19.210896, 50.199005
                        19.211217, 50.199747
                        19.211647, 50.200228
                        19.212054, 50.200592
                        19.212301, 50.200598 </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
```

Answer (score 1):

A I thought this was really silly mistake. It was necessary to transform placemark to Spherical Mercator Projection. Here is my code:

```
test_placemark = f.read(data.outerHTML);
test_placemark[0].geometry.transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
);
```